# Can I reuse colors in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I've got several yellow buttons created using Inteface Builder. All have the same color. Currently I declare color in each xib. Can I declared it globally and reuse across all xibs?

Comment: What part of "in Interface Builder" did every single person who answered this question fail to understand? Weird.

Comment: @MarkAmery That means, the only way to do this is to use _code_.

Comment: It's silly really that there is not way to do this. Who wants to adjust a color across 100 pages one by one in IB?

Answer (score 7):

**Not possible in Interface Builder.** Do it in code, for example by creating special subclass of the button.

You could use system Color Palette to save the color, but you still need to apply it to all buttons every time you decide to change it. Or you can just use Recently Used Colors in the color chooser, but neither way is enough dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this.

At the bottom of the color picker popup in Interface Builder, there's a row of squares you can use to store colors for later use. Drag a color into it from the rectangle where the current color is shown at the top of the color picker to store it, and then just click a stored color later to use it.

[image: diagram showing how to save colors]

Comment: This will not allow you to re-apply color when you decide to change it. But this is the only primitive way to save colors for manual re-use.

Comment: @iMartin You're right that this is a concern, and I hadn't considered it. With some hackery, you can still swap a color globally when using this method, though. If you want to change a color across your storyboard, just do a find and replace of all occurrences of the tag representing that color in the underlying XML of the Storyboard (or of all the XIBs in your project). It's a hack, but it'll work, and it's not something you'll need to do often.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this entirely in interface builder, unfortunately.  However, you can come pretty close with a little bit of code.  The best way I've found to be able to change colors throughout the app in one go is to subclass the item that you want to color (UILabel, for instance) to set the color upon initialization:

```
@interface HuedUILabel : UILabel
@end

@implementation HuedUILabel

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.textColor = [AppConfig primaryColor];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then, set the label to have a custom class in IB:

[image]

Now, when you want to change the color of all your UILabels, you can do it by changing your one color def AND you don't have to clutter your code with a bunch of appearance assignments.

Answer (score -1):

Most definitely!

Create a singleton object (you can call it `OksanaColor`, to be cool)...

... or, if you're really lazy, a read-only `UIColor` property that you can access from your app delegate.

Answer (score -1):

You can also add a category on UIColor, so you can use it same as when you use UIColor.  For example in my App I add a new file called ApplicationColors which contains all my app colors.

```
@interface UIColor (ApplicationColours)

+(UIColor *)savaColor;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation UIColor (ApplicationColours)

+(UIColor *)savaColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:228.0f/255.0f green:86.0f/255.0f blue:86.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];  

}

@end
```

Then to use it in my app, I import the ApplicationColours.h and use the same as any other UIColor. i.e:

```
label.textColor = [UIColor savaColor];
```

Comment: You might want to make +savaColor keep a static variable for that color, so that it's not creating a new instance each time.

Comment: I don't want to do it in code. I want to set inside interface builder.

Comment: In that case then you can't use them globally.  Interface builder does keep a list of recently used colors, but they are not global, each color you select gets stored in the xib somewhere.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a very simple implementation of a named colors category for `UIColor`.  With this code in your project, `UIColor` will remember any colors you want to save, and will let you access your own colors or system colors using `+colorWithName:`

```
@interface UIColor (namedColors)

+ (UIColor *) colorWithName:(NSString *) name;
+ (void) setColor:(UIColor *) color forName:(NSString *) name;

@end

static NSMutableDictionary *colorStorage;

@implementation UIColor (namedColors)

+ (NSMutableDictionary *) colorStorage
{
  if (!colorStorage)
    colorStorage = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
  return colorStorage;
}

+ (UIColor *) colorWithName:(NSString *) name
{
  UIColor *result =[[self colorStorage] valueForKey:name];  // See if we have a color with this name in the colorStorage.

  if (result) return result;

  SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(name);  // look for a class method whose selector matches the given name, such as "blueColor" or "clearColor".

  if ([self respondsToSelector:selector] && (result = [self performSelector:selector]))
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[self class]])
      return result;

  return nil;   
}

+ (void) setColor:(UIColor *) color forName:(NSString *) name
{
  [[self colorStorage] setValue:color forKey:name];
}

@end
```

Comment: Maybe too complicated? Simple `[UIColor myRedColor]` or `[UIColor anotherRedColor]` would be enough and simplier, no?